# What does the end-user need to run applications using .NET Standard?

Tags: .net, .net-standard

In the following link, there are all flavors of .NET but Standard:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Is there any .NET Standard redistributable necessary to install first, for an end user to run an application leveraging .NET Standard ?

Comment: the .net standard isn't a runtime. you need either .net core, xamarian, mono, .net framework, etc...

Comment: it all depends. how are you building the app?

Comment: Okay, I think I got it, the application is a desktop application, so one only needs the regular .NET Framework, right ?

Comment: maybe - you can also write a console application in .net core.

Comment: Yes you can, an obvious thing would be one needs .NET Core in such case, thanks for pointing me out in the right direction.

Comment: Here is a good analogy using classes and interfaces https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/metaphor.md

Comment: Okay that's clear now, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Standard defines the set of APIs the must be provided by a compatible runtime. So any of .Net Framework, Mono, or .Net Core (or even new products) are able to implement the requirements of a particular .Net Standard version, and any program that claims to be compatible with that version of .Net Standard will be able to use that runtime, regardless of platform.